# Parse HTML with the QXmlStreamReader in Qt 5.8 with MSVC 2015

Tags: qt, html-parsing, qxmlstreamreader

I try to get some data from a webpage in Qt. Since [QWebKit is unmaintained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676800/how-to-parse-html-with-c-qt) I would like to use `QXmlStreamReader` but it I get error messages for some Webpages.

For example: `XML Parse Error  "Opening and ending tag mismatch."` at http://www.google.com

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=toP_WMrVKoHKXuvxnsAO">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

And I get `HTML`, `HEAD`, `meta` and `TITLE`.

Other error messages on valid html pages:

- XML Parse Error  "Expected '-' or 'DOCTYPE', but got '[a-zA-Z]'."
- XML Parse Error  "Entity 'raquo' not declared."

Here is my Code:

```
webpage = new QXmlStreamReader(data);

//emit got_webpage(&QString(data));

QStringList test;

while (!webpage->atEnd() && !webpage->hasError())
{
    QXmlStreamReader::TokenType token = webpage->readNext();

    if (token == QXmlStreamReader::StartDocument)
        continue;

    if (token == QXmlStreamReader::StartElement)
    {
        test << webpage->name().toString();
        /*if (webpage->name() == "H1")
        {
            emit got_webpage(webpage)
        }*/
    }
}

emit got_webpage(&test.join("\n"));

if (webpage->hasError())
{
    // TODO: Error handling...
    qDebug() << "XML Parse Error " << webpage->errorString();
}

webpage->clear();
delete webpage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, `QXmlStreamReader` is meant for parsing XML. HTML is not based on XML, so it cannot be parsed with `QXmlStreamReader`.

That said, if you can convert the HTML into [XHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML), you will be able to parse it with `QXmlStreamReader`. However, Qt has no built-in method of performing this conversion. It is possible to convert arbitrary HTML to XHTML with 3rd party libraries such as [tidylib](http://www.html-tidy.org/).

Comment: And is there a build in way to parse HTML with Qt? I thought I could use `QXmlStreamReader` because of the answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676800/how-to-parse-html-with-c-qt?noredirect=1&lq=1) thread.

Comment: No, Qt has no built-in HTML parser. For an explanation of why they removed it in Qt WebEngine, [read this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html).

Comment: Hm I cant find any Infos about an old HTML parser in QWebEngine. I think I'll lock for a 3rd party library.