# Regular expression for parsing particular HTML list

Tags: html, regex, html-select

I have a number of lists in a string:

```
<select id="first">
  <option value="0">Val11</option>
  <option value="0">Val12</option>
  <option value="0">Val13</option>
</select>
<select id="second">
  <option value="0">Val21</option>
  <option value="0">Val22</option>
  <option value="0">Val23</option>
</select>
<select id="third">
  <option value="0">Val31</option>
  <option value="0">Val32</option>
  <option value="0">Val33</option>
</select>
```

I can parse values in general, but how can I parse the values of certain list, say, of list with id="second".
I want to get only

```
Val21
Val22
Val23
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't mentioned, I use it in QRegularExpression and QRegularExpressionMatchIterator

Comment: Sorry, but isn't there a better way to parse HTML in Qt? See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676800/how-to-parse-html-with-c-qt).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help:

```
<option.+?>(.+?)</option>
```

It will match anything inside the "option" tags.
The stuff in the parenthesis is the data you are looking for, you can access it with "$1", or "\1".

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I need to parse a particular list. not all