# QXmlQuery::setQuery() cannot query when I pass source code to its parameter

Tags: c++, qt, xquery

Qt's QXmlQuery::setQuery has a polymorphism, just like:

```cpp
void QXmlQuery::setQuery(const QString &sourceCode, const QUrl &documentURI = QUrl())
```

However, when I pass a HTML source code to **the parameter `sourceCode`**, and try to evaluate, I can only get an error:

> Error XPST0003 in file:///, at line 1, column 2: syntax error, unexpected unknown keyword, expecting QName or NCName

Here is an example:

```cpp
QString srcHTML = "<html>......</html>";    // An HTML forked from any website

QXmlQuery query;
query.setQuery(srcHTML, QUrl("/html/body/"));

QString r;
query.evaluateTo(&r);

qDebug() << r;
```

Then an error message shows:

> Error XPST0003 in file:///html/body/, at line 1, column 2: syntax error, unexpected unknown keyword, expecting QName or NCName
>   ""

That's strange, even though I've feeded QXmlQuery::setQuery() a valid HTML source!

Comment: Maybe, it is about the second parameter, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html#details . Check if QUrl is valid.

Comment: @sirop The example in my code comes from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677398/10865463

Comment: Then could you explain:`query.setQuery("doc('index.html')/html/body/p[1]");`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `query.setFocus(srcHTML); query.setQuery("/html/body");`. Note that the input string to setFocus needs to be well-formed XML which HTML often not is.

Comment: So does it. Maybe I have to find another way to parse HTML.