# QXmlQuery fails to convert xml to html with setQuery(QString)

Tags: html, xml, qt, xslt, qxmlquery

When I use `setQuery(QUrl(file.xsl))`, then it works. But if I load the file into a `QString` and call `setQuery(theString)`, then subsequent `evaluateTo()` fails (bool exception and empty result).

What can be wrong here?

Remarkable is that `setFocus()` does work both with `QUrl(file.xml)` and with `QString` loaded from the file.

Comment: Possibly related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556982/qxmlquerysetquery-cannot-query-when-i-pass-source-code-to-its-parameter

Comment: Does `setQuery(theString, QUrl(file.xsl))` solve your problem?

Comment: @m7913d 1) I don't want `setQuery` access any file (I need xsl to be in memory), 2) even if your variant worked, why it would need both file and its content in `theString`?

Comment: [Qt doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlquery.html#setQuery-2): "... documentURI [_second arg_] represents the query obtained from the sourceCode device. It is the base URI of the static context, as defined in the XQuery language. It is used internally to resolve relative URIs that appear in the query, and for message reporting. ..." Does that make sense?

Comment: `setQuery(theString, QUrl(file.xsl))` does work indeed, but then it's better just  `setQuery(QUrl(file.xsl))`
very strange; Qt doc is unclear: can I pass xsl file content, but not file path?

Comment: `setQuery(theString, QUrl(file.xsl))` may perform better if you already have downloaded `theString` for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is:

- my xsl contains `document('')` expression, with empty URL, to refer to the xsl itself;
- Qt tries to resolve the URL using base URL;
- and base URL is the path of my exe application file, this is Qt behaviour: application path is considered as base URL if it's omitted in `setQuery()` call;
- so the URL of the document is resolved as exe path - then it tries to load it as xml and throws exception.

Except this case, `setQuery(QString)` is generally ok itself.